# parsing xml using xpath

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the following xml document:

```
<DynaCal>
  <Events>
    <Event>
      <ShortDesc>7th Grade Volleyball BBC Tournament: Pettisville vs. Hilltop/Edon winner in Match 4 of the day.  Match 1 begins at 9:00 AM</ShortDesc>
      <Date>10/15/2011</Date>
      <LocationDesc>Fayette High School</LocationDesc>
      <Time>9:00 AM</Time>
    </Event>

    <Event>
      <ShortDesc>8th Grade Volleyball BBC Tournament: Pettisville vs. Stryker/North Central winner in Match 3 of the day.  Match 1 begins at 9:00 AM</ShortDesc>
      <Date>10/15/2011</Date>
      <LocationDesc>Fayette High School</LocationDesc>
      <Time>9:00 AM</Time>
    </Event>

    <Event>
      <ShortDesc>Varsity Cross Country Practice</ShortDesc>
      <Date>10/15/2011</Date>
      <LocationDesc>Oak Openings</LocationDesc>
      <Time>9:00 AM - 11:30 AM</Time>
    </Event>

    <Event>
      <ShortDesc>Varsity Cross Country Practice</ShortDesc>
      <Date>10/17/2011</Date>
      <LocationDesc>Pettisville School</LocationDesc>
      <Time>3:15 PM - 5:30 PM</Time>
    </Event>

    <Event>
      <ShortDesc>Varsity Volleyball Practice</ShortDesc>
      <Date>10/17/2011</Date>
      <LocationDesc>Pettisville Varsity Gym</LocationDesc>
      <Time>3:30 PM - 5:30 PM</Time>
    </Event>

    <Event>
      <ShortDesc>Varsity Cross Country Practice</ShortDesc>
      <Date>10/18/2011</Date>
      <LocationDesc>Oak Openings</LocationDesc>
      <Time>3:15 PM - 5:30 PM</Time>
    <Event>
  </Events>
</DynaCal>
```

document and would like to display it so all Events with same date display

```
<h4>Date 1</h4>
<p>ShortDesc</p>
<p>Time</p>
<p>ShortDesc</p>
<p>Time</p>

<h4>Date 2</h4>
<p>ShortDesc</p>
<p>Time</p>
<p>ShortDesc</p>
<p>Time</p>
```

I can easily parse the xml and pull back those items, I am very new to php and how to set up an array to find a child element (Date) and display all Events within that date, then move on to the next date.

Comment: Hi, if my answer assisted you, would you tick it as the correct answer? This assigns some reputation points to users who answer questions - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in parts. Firstly, grab each event, and then de-duplicate in PHP. Something like this:

```
$values = array();
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
foreach ($xml->xpath('/DynaCal/Events/Event') as $event)
{
    // Add your values to an array here
    $values[]['shortDesc'] = $event->ShortDesc;

    // Then dedup here (add items conditionally depending on date)
}

// Or dedup here after the loop is done... :)
```